# HTML5 audio not scaling on iPhone

Tags: html, html5-audio, retina-display

I got a request on a friends website. There are HTML5 elements and the play button is barely visible on the iPhone (using a 5s). it shifts up until you zoom in to the 100% zoom. I added the viewport meta tag and CSS

```
audio {
    height:0;
    width:0;
}
```

but no luck. Any ideas?

site: http://bit.ly/1Hy9I57

Comment: Please provide a proper SSCCE.

Comment: added the link - sorry

Comment: That's not an [SSCCE](http://sscce.org/). Creating such will help isolate / identify the specific issue .. possibly resolving it in the process.